# How to fix this errror builtins.TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, path, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a code that allow user to select from desired path  folder and display in a QlistWidget the existing docx files.

The problem is that the when the user select a file the system must return the full path of the file. But instead it display the below error:

> builtins.TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not
>   builtin_function_or_method

i know that the error is in **FileListSelected function** in this line :

```
p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath.index)
```

but do not know how to fix it.

examples this is the result of the CheckPath print:

## where these are the existing files in the **Download** directory.

- checkpath  Full Path=> C:\Users\test\Downloads\cv.docx
- checkpath  Displayed Path => Downloads\cv.docx

=========================================

- checkpath  Full Path=> C:\Users\test\Downloads\Volunteer Card.docx
- checkpath  Displayed Path => Downloads\Volunteer Card.docx

=========================================

- checkpath  Full Path=> C:\Users\test\Downloads\insta
  maro\followers.docx
- checkpath  Displayed Path => insta maro\followers.docx

=========================================

- checkpath  Full Path=>
  C:\Users\test\Downloads\PdfToText-master\examples\text-
- capture\sample-report.doc checkpath  Displayed Path =>
  text-capture\sample-report.doc

## code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QMimeData)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QMenu,QListWidgetItem)

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pdfviewer
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import os
import re
from os import path

import docx


class pdfViewer(pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):

    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj):
        pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow.__init__(self)

        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()


        self.ExportButton.clicked.connect(self.openExport)        
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clicked.connect(self.FileListSelected)



    def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane


        p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath.index)
        print("this is P==>{}".format(p))
        if self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems():
            Item = p , "\\" , self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[0].text()            
            print("this is the cuurent Item =={}".format(Item)) 
            print("===============================================")
            return Item

        else:
            print("<b>!!! NO SELECTED FILE !!!</b>\n")


    def setExistingDirectory(self):               # create a pop up fileDirectory Dialog Message  in order to select the desired folder.

        self.fileList=[]
        dialog = QDialog()
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly 
        Folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(dialog, "Open Folder" ,options=options)
        return Folder

    def checkPath(self,folder):         # Funtion to check the given path for the wanted extension (Files)

    try:
        directory=folder

        whichChecked=""
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

            for filename in files:
                if len(self.lineEdit_Ext.text())>0:
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("Enter The Filetype Extention Here")

                    if filename.endswith(self.lineEdit_Ext.text()):
                        fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        print(fullPath)
                        self.fileList.append(fullPath)

                elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                    self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)

                    self.p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)
                    print("checkpath  Full Path=> {}".format(self.p))
                    oneDir = os.path.join(*self.p.parts[-2:])                    
                    print("checkpath  Displayed Path => {}".format(oneDir))
                    print("=========================================")
                    self.fileList.append(oneDir)                        
                    whichChecked="docx - doc Ext was Selected"

                if len(self.fileList) > 0:
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("bacground-color:white;")
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("{0}".format(whichChecked))
                else:
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:Red")
                    self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("No Ext is Specified")                            


        self.ListFilesInViewer(self.fileList)           # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist 
        self.SelectAll.setEnabled(True)

        return folder

    except Exception as e:
        print("this error occure {0}".format(e))

    def ListFilesInViewer(self,Files):              # Function to list all the files in the Left pane 
        for item1 in Files:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item1)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidgetPDFlist.addItem(item)
            self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setText(str(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()))        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    pdfViewerUi = pdfViewer(PdfPreviewWindow)
    PdfPreviewWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## pdfviewer.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\tests_scripts\qt_creator\wse_stakckOverFlow\pdfviewer.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_PdfPreviewWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, PdfPreviewWindow):
        PdfPreviewWindow.setObjectName("PdfPreviewWindow")
        PdfPreviewWindow.resize(767, 502)
        PdfPreviewWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(749, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.ExportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.ExportButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/export.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ExportButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.ExportButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.ExportButton.setFlat(True)
        self.ExportButton.setObjectName("ExportButton")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ExportButton, 2, 2, 1, 3)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setFont(font)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setObjectName("groupBoxPDFlist")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.SelectAll = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.SelectAll.setEnabled(True)
        self.SelectAll.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.SelectAll.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/checkBox.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.SelectAll.setIcon(icon1)
        self.SelectAll.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.SelectAll.setDefault(False)
        self.SelectAll.setFlat(True)
        self.SelectAll.setObjectName("SelectAll")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SelectAll, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(89, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setObjectName("listWidgetPDFlist")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidgetPDFlist, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBoxPDFlist, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.groupBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.groupBox_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setFont(font)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Open.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(36, 36))
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setDefault(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setFlat(True)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setObjectName("pushButtonOpenFolder")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButtonOpenFolder)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.rdBtn_docx = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/File Format Doc-507x507"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setIcon(icon3)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.rdBtn_docx.setObjectName("rdBtn_docx")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.rdBtn_docx)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.lineEdit_Ext = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setObjectName("lineEdit_Ext")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_Ext)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(158, 18, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.formLayout.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 0, 1, 6)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setFont(font)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setObjectName("lineEditTotalPDFnumber")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber)
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber.setObjectName("labelTotalPDFnumber")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.labelTotalPDFnumber)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(502, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 5, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        PdfPreviewWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 767, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        PdfPreviewWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        PdfPreviewWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PdfPreviewWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, PdfPreviewWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PdfPreviewWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "فرع التحليل - محرّك البحث "))
        self.ExportButton.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">نسخ</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Files List"))
        self.SelectAll.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Check All Items</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Search Panel"))
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">فتح مجلّد</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Enter The FileType Extention Here"))
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber.setText(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Total"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "البرنامج"))

import resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PdfPreviewWindow()
    ui.setupUi(PdfPreviewWindow)
    PdfPreviewWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I just read quickly, but it seems like you have an uncalled function somewhere. Are you sure it's not supposed to be something like `self.fullPath().index` or `self.fullPath.index()` ?

Comment: @AlexandreUzan yes https://stackoverflow.com/tagsbecause **fullPath** is the variable that handles the return full path from the CheckPath function ....
the problem is that i don't know how to transfer the returned full path from the checkPath function into FileListSelected function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you return something in the function "setExistingDirectory" and after that you start an **elif** instead of an if. So the code after the first "return Folder" should not be reached. If it would be reached, it would throw an exception.

That means, that fullPath is never evlaluated.

```
def setExistingDirectory(self):               # create a pop up fileDirectory Dialog Message  in order to select the desired folder.

        self.fileList=[]
        dialog = QDialog()
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly 
        Folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(dialog, "Open Folder" ,options=options)
        return Folder


                    elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
```

Comment: I see, the FullPath variable is created in setExistingDirectory. You can try and set a breakpoint at the following line: self.p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)

Maybe it is not possible to reach that point, as it also starts with an elif, which is strange.

Comment: OK, there are also some more typos in setExistingDirectory like "return folder" vs. "return Folder".

Comment: i will  edit the question  and add example of the displayed results

Comment: **folder** is an argument of the checkPath() function

Comment: i edit my question and add function **checkPath()** that includes the **elif statement**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like self.fullPath is already a string since you're doing:

```
self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
```

which returns a string.

So then when you do `self.fullPath.index` you are calling the index attribute of `str` which is a builtin function, thus the `builtins.TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not builtin_function_or_method`.

My best guess would be to check all the occurrences of self.fullPath to see if it always the object it is supposed to be.

Comment: take a look to the update question i added  examples